# How to allow any number of any attributes with XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

How to implement simple `<table>` tag matching with XSD?

The following does not work:

```
<xs:element name="table">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="td" 
                        minOccurs="0" 
                        maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                        type="MixedTemplateContentContainer"/>  
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

If I use any attribute in table tag it fails:

```
<table ccc="table" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr align="center"><td>
```

saying

> Attribute 'ccc' is not allowed to appear in element 'table'.

Comment: That's what you get for using XML to try and define HTML.  Especially non-conforming HTML.

Comment: I don't want to define HTML, I want to define some bunch of XMLs which contain some HTML-like insertions.

Comment: Would specifying the lax processing model (on the anyAttributes) help? Default would be strict.

Comment: If you restrict your table element to what is defined in XHTML, you can write up a schema to describe it, based more or less on the definitions around the end of http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd (the XSD definition of XHTML Transitional).  If you want arbitrary XML in there, check out `processContents="skip"`.  I'm not sure there's an in-between, though.

Comment: @MarvinSmit I met lax processing declaration once and I think it is kind of magic. What is wrong without `lax`? Doesn't `anyAttribute` declaration mean any attribute already?

Comment: `anyAttribute` with `processContents="strict"` means any declared attribute may be used, without your needing to list it by name.  Since you haven't declared a `ccc` attribute, its occurrence is not valid.  It matches the wildcard all right, but it lacks a declaration, which makes it invalid.  If you want to accept undeclared attributes, you need `processContents="lax"` (or `"skip"`).

Answer (score 10):

I ran this with the Saxon schema processor, and got the error message

Validation error on line 1 of test.xml:
  XSD99999: The `<xs:anyAttribute>` that matches attribute @ccc requires strict validation,
  but no attribute declaration is available

Essentially, `<xs:anyAttribute>` has a `processContents` attribute, and the default value is strict, which means you are allowed any attribute you like provided that there is a matching attribute declaration in the schema. You probably want processContents="lax" or "skip". The value lax means that the attribute is validated against a matching attribute declaration if the schema contains one, and if not is accepted anyway. The value skip means that any attribute is accepted without validation.

Answer (score 3):

Set the **processContents** attribute of your **`<xs:anyAttribute>`** element to **`skip`**:

```
<xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" />
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Making your full XSD:

```
<xs:element name="table">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="tr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="td" 
                        minOccurs="0" 
                        maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                        type="MixedTemplateContentContainer"/>  
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? Is it

> How to allow any number of any attributes with XSD?

or

> How to implement simple  tag matching with XSD?

because they seem quite different questions.

The answer to the first is to use `xs:anyAttribute`.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Do you mean "my requirement is not met by xs:anyAttribute" -- in which case, please explain your requirement better -- or do you mean "I tried using xs:anyAttribute and got an error message" -- in which case tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed. Or do you mean something else? And by the way, my answer took the form of a request for clarification of your question, it would be nice if you could answer my question.

Comment: I gave all of (1) xsd snippet (it contains `xs:anyAttribute` declaration inside `table` tag description as one can see), (2) xml snippet (it contains `table` tag as one can see) and (3) error message (which is saying that `table` tag can't contain attribute `ccc` which is in apparent contradiction with declaration). What else can I give? Don't try to catch me and expect I can give what I don't understand.